# The usual Twitt_Sharing class giving error

Tags: java, android, twitter, twitter4j

Here is the class:

```
package com.twitter.android;

import java.io.File;

import twitter4j.StatusUpdate;
import twitter4j.Twitter;
import twitter4j.TwitterException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.twitter.android.Twitter_Handler.TwDialogListener;

public class Twitt_Sharing {

    private final Twitter_Handler mTwitter;
    private final Activity activity;
    private String twitt_msg;
    private File image_path;

    public Twitt_Sharing( Activity act, String consumer_key, String consumer_secret ) {
        this.activity = act;
        mTwitter = new Twitter_Handler(activity, consumer_key, consumer_secret);
    }

    public void shareToTwitter(String msg, File Image_url) {
        this.twitt_msg = msg;
        this.image_path = Image_url;
        mTwitter.setListener(mTwLoginDialogListener);

        if (mTwitter.hasAccessToken()) {
            // this will post data in asyn background thread
            showTwittDialog();
        } else {
            mTwitter.authorize();
        }
    }

    private void showTwittDialog() {

        new PostTwittTask().execute(twitt_msg);

    }

    private final TwDialogListener mTwLoginDialogListener = new TwDialogListener() {

        @Override
        public void onError(String value) {
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    showToast("Login Failed");
                    mTwitter.resetAccessToken();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(String value) {
            showTwittDialog();
        }
    };

    void showToast(final String msg) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(activity, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

    }

    class PostTwittTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(activity);
            pDialog.setMessage("Posting Twitt...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... twitt) {
            try {
                // mTwitter.updateStatus(twitt[0]);
                // File imgFile = new File("/sdcard/bluetooth/Baby.jpg");

                return Share_Pic_Text_Titter(image_path, twitt_msg, mTwitter.twitterObj);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (e.getMessage().toString().contains("duplicate")) {
                    return "Posting Failed because of Duplicate message...";
                }
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Posting Failed!!!";
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {

            super.onPostExecute(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
            if (null != result && result.equals("success")) {
                activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        showToast(result);
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    }

    public String Share_Pic_Text_Titter(File image_path, String message, Twitter twitter)
            throws Exception {
        String Status = "";
        try {

            StatusUpdate st = new StatusUpdate(message);
 --------------------------**Error in the line below**--------------------------------
            st.setMedia(image_path);
            twitter.updateStatus(st);
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Successfully update on Twitter...!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Status = "success";
            /*
             * Toast.makeText(activity, "Successfully update on Twitter...!",
             * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             */
        } catch (TwitterException e) {
            Status = "fail";
            Log.v("log_tag", "Pic Upload error" + e);
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(activity, "Ooopss..!!! Failed to update on Twitter.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }
        return Status;
    }

    public void Authorize_UserDetail() {

    }
}
```

Now in the line st.setMedia(image_path); it is showing error which states The method *setMedia(File) is undefined for the type StatusUpdate* Has anyone ever faced this.?

Comment: What version of the Twitter api are you using?

Comment: twitter4j-core-2.1.11.jar and twitter4j-media-support-4.0.2.jar

Comment: [According to the Docs](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/StatusUpdate.html#setMedia-java.io.File-) that method is only available in Twitter4j v2.2.5+. *Discalimer: I've never used the Twitter api*

Comment: Ya I updated and it got fine. Can you please post it as an answer.?

Comment: Can you please help me with a code where I am able to post image on fb but not text. It was working earlier but I dont know where it got messed up. Can you please have a look once.?

Comment: If you have a post, I can try but I have never used that SDK either. Someone else would probably know better. But, if you know it was working, you can slowly go through recent changes to try and pinpoint the problem and where/when it stopped working.

Comment: (here is the code as a ques.)[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26365568/unable-to-post-fb-status-where-as-image-getting-updated-from-android-app], I know its impossible to understand this. However if you wish to help, here is the project, which works with image sharing but not text. You can download and check. I will be really thankful. (Here is the link to download project.)[https://www.dropbox.com/s/uo6l0v60wg7lr9p/1push.rar?dl=0]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[According to the documentation](http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/StatusUpdate.html#setMedia-java.io.File-), the method `setMedia(File file)` is available in Twitter 4j v2.2.5+ so it is unable to find that method in versions below this.

Updating to a newer version solves the problem.